# Leaflet Map error on jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, leaflet

I'm adding a simple map on jqm. The issue I am getting in console is:

GET http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/NaN/0/0.png 404 (Not Found)

**JS:**

```
var map = L.map('map');
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {maxZoom: 18}).addTo(map);
})
```

On a click function adding a Marker with:

```
L.marker([39, -6.85]).bindPopup("test").addTo(map); 
map.panTo(L.latLng[39, -6.85]);
```

Using leaflet 0.8. It seems that the {z} var is for some reason not getting to the TileLayer.

This will happen also by only loading the map, without ading the marker, so I suppose it is something internal to the leaflet library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling setView at some stage.

```
map.setView([0, 0], 18);
```

or better yet:

```
map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 18})
```

Also Looks like you are trying to call / get L.lngLng function with some kind of array index... try this instead: -- also note pageinit is deprecated in JQM 1.4+

```
map.panTo([39, -6.85]);
```